# Python string variable values can I concatenate the values and return the value in my function

Tags: python-2.7, beautifulsoup

I have the following function with a few print statements.  In each print statement I would like to return it's value so I can use that and add it to my email code which will send each string text into an email.

I tried to concatenate each string into a variable and return it at the bottom of the function.
e.g.

```
p_text = p_start_time + p_duration + p_status
return  p_text
```

I get the error:

```
    File "E:/test_runners 2 edit project in progress add more tests/selenium_regression_test_5_1_1/Email/email_selenium_report.py", line 30, in <module>
    report.extract_data_from_report_htmltestrunner()
  File "E:\test_runners 2 edit project in progress add more tests\selenium_regression_test_5_1_1\Email\report.py", line 400, in extract_data_from_report_htmltestrunner
    p_text = p_start_time + p_duration + p_status
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'Tag' and 'Tag'
```

My function implementation is:

```
def extract_data_from_report_htmltestrunner():
    filename = (r"E:\test_runners 2 edit project\selenium_regression_test_5_1_1\TestReport\ClearCore501_Automated_GUI_TestReport.html")
    html_report_part = open(filename,'r')
    soup = BeautifulSoup(html_report_part, "html.parser")

    div_heading = soup.find('div', {'class': 'heading'})
    p_start_time = div_heading.find('strong', text='Start Time:').parent
    p_start_time.find(text=True, recursive=False)
    print p_start_time.text
    p_duration = div_heading.find('strong', text='Duration:').parent
    p_duration.find(text=True, recursive=False)
    print p_duration.text
    p_status = div_heading.find('strong', text='Status:').parent
    p_status.find(text=True, recursive=False)
    print p_status.text
    #p_text = p_start_time + p_duration + p_status

    table = soup.select_one("#result_table")
    headers = [td.text for td in table.select_one("#header_row").find_all("td")[1:-1]]
    print(" ".join(headers))
    for row in table.select("tr.passClass"):
        print(" ".join([td.text for td in row.find_all("td")[1:-1]]))
    #return  p_text
```

In each of my print statements how can i return it as a string variable?
Once I have it returned I can include it in the message part of my email code.

Even this print statement in teh for loop I would like to return it in a string variable somehow.

```
print(" ".join([td.text for td in row.find_all("td")[1:-1]]))
```

Thanks, Riaz

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> `p_text = p_start_time + p_duration + p_status`

In this expression, all the operands are [`Tag` instances](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#tag) which you cannot glue together with `+`. What you can do is to *cast them to strings* and then concatenate:

```
p_text = "".join(map(str, [p_start_time, p_duration, p_status]))
```

Comment: Thanks, this works.  I am getting the output with the html tags.  <p class="attribute"><strong>Start Time:</strong> 2016-08-12 11:57:33</p><p class="attribute"><strong>Duration:</strong> 0:48:09.007000</p><p class="attribute"><strong>Status:</strong> Pass 75</p>

Comment: Can i strip out the html tags?

Comment: @RiazLadhani ah, misunderstood the problem a bit. Call '.get_text()' on each of the 'Tag' instances.

Comment: Got it.  Thanks very much for you help.